# Kubernetes: external service is not available from all minions on Azure cloud

Tags: azure, load-balancing, kubernetes

I've got the following cluster of 3 Ubuntu machines on Azure cloud:

```
172.16.0.7 (master)
172.16.0.4 (kube-01)
172.16.0.5 (kube-02)
```

On `172.16.0.4 (kube-01)` I've got a pod called **publisher** with port **8080** exposed. To make it available to the world I defined the following service:

```
"id": "publisher-service",
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1beta1",
  "port": 8181,
  "containerPort": 8080,
  "publicIPs": ["172.16.0.4", "172.16.0.5"],
  "selector": {
    "group": "abc",
    "component": "publisher"
  },
  "labels": {
    "group": "abc"
  }
```

- `172.16.0.4` and `172.16.0.5` are Internal IP Addressess (Azure terms) of `kube-01` and `kube-02` respectively
- On `172.16.0.4 (kube-01)` I've got an Azure endpoint defined with public port set to **8181** and private port set to **8181**
- On `172.16.0.5 (kube-02)` I've got an Azure endpoint defined with public port set to **8182** and private port set to **8181**

With such a setup I can successfully access `publisher-service` using my VM public virtual IP (VIP) address and port **8181**.

However I would expect to be also able to reach the `publisher-service` using the same VIP address and port **8182** (as it is mapped to port **8181** on `kube-02`). Instead `curl` reports `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

**Am I doing anything wrong here? Maybe my understanding of [Kubernetes External Services](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/services.md#external-services) is incorrect (and hence my expectation is wrong)?**

I also noticed in `/var/log/upstart/kube-proxy` the following entries logged:

```
E0404 17:36:33.371889    1661 proxier.go:82] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.0.86.26:8080: i/o timeout
E0404 17:36:33.371951    1661 proxier.go:110] Failed to connect to balancer: failed to connect to an endpoint.
```

Here is a part of `iptables -L -t nat` output captured on `172.16.0.5 (kube-02)`:

```
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             11.1.1.2             /* kubernetes */ tcp dpt:https redir ports 45717
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             11.1.1.1             /* kubernetes-ro */ tcp dpt:http redir ports 34122
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             11.1.1.221           /* publisher-service */ tcp dpt:8181 redir ports 48046
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             172.16.0.4           /* publisher-service */ tcp dpt:8181 redir ports 48046
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             172.16.0.5           /* publisher-service */ tcp dpt:8181 redir ports 48046

Chain KUBE-PORTALS-HOST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             11.1.1.2             /* kubernetes */ tcp dpt:https to:172.16.0.5:45717
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             11.1.1.1             /* kubernetes-ro */ tcp dpt:http to:172.16.0.5:34122
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             11.1.1.221           /* publisher-service */ tcp dpt:8181 to:172.16.0.5:48046
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             172.16.0.4           /* publisher-service */ tcp dpt:8181 to:172.16.0.5:48046
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             172.16.0.5           /* publisher-service */ tcp dpt:8181 to:172.16.0.5:48046
```

I am using Kubernetes v0.12.0. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu_multinodes_cluster.md) to setup my cluster (i.e. I'm using flannel).

---

**UPDATE #1**: added `publisher` pod status info.

```
apiVersion: v1beta1
creationTimestamp: 2015-04-04T13:24:47Z
currentState:
  Condition:
  - kind: Ready
    status: Full
  host: 172.16.0.4
  hostIP: 172.16.0.4
  info:
    publisher:
      containerID: docker://6eabf71d507ad0086b37940931aa739534ef681906994a6aae6d97b8b213
      image: xxxxx.cloudapp.net/publisher:0.0.2
      imageID: docker://5a76329ae2d0dce05fae6f7b1216e346cef2e5aa49899cd829a5dc1f6e70
      ready: true
      restartCount: 5
      state:
        running:
          startedAt: 2015-04-04T13:26:24Z
  manifest:
    containers: null
    id: ""
    restartPolicy: {}
    version: ""
    volumes: null
  podIP: 10.0.86.26
  status: Running
desiredState:
  manifest:
    containers:
    - capabilities: {}
      command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - java -jar publisher.jar -b $KAFKA_SERVICE_HOST:$KAFKA_SERVICE_PORT
      image: xxxxx.cloudapp.net/publisher:0.0.2
      imagePullPolicy: PullIfNotPresent
      name: publisher
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
        hostPort: 8080
        protocol: TCP
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    id: ""
    restartPolicy:
      always: {}
    version: v1beta2
    volumes: null
generateName: rc-publisher-
id: rc-publisher-ls6k1
kind: Pod
labels:
  group: abc
namespace: default
resourceVersion: 22853
selfLink: /api/v1beta1/pods/rc-publisher-ls6k1?namespace=default
uid: f746555d-dacd-11e4-8ae7-000d3a101fda
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I reinstalled my cluster using k8s **v0.14.2** everything started to work as expected. I followed Brendan Burns [Docker Guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.md).

Comment: alright. for external access, do you have request comes in to one node (via the opened port/endpoint) and let kubernetes services handle the load balancing ?

Comment: All requests go through one node/endpoint with nginx proxying websocket traffic to k8s service portal address.

Answer (score 0):

The external networking actually appears to be working fine -- the message you see in the logs is because the kube-proxy did receive the request you sent to it.

The reason it failed, though, is that the kube-proxy couldn't talk to your pod. Either flannel is failing to route to your pod's IP properly, or the pod isn't healthy. Since sending requests to 172.16.0.4 works, it's likely that something is wrong with your flannel setup. You can confirm this by trying to curl 10.0.86.26:8080 from node-2.

In case it may be something wrong with the health of the pod, you can check its detailed state by running `kubectl.sh get pod $POD_NAME --output=yaml`.

Sorry for the difficulties!

Comment: Indeed curl to `10.0.86.26:8080` timeouts. I've added pod status info to the question body. Note that the `restartCount: 5` is not an issue - I restarted this pod myself while trying different settings. One more thing: I also checked minions status - nothing suspicious there.

Comment: Any ideas how to check flannel setup?

Comment: FYI, I didn't find a fix for this issue although I found I could reach my `publisher-service` when its k8s definition didn't use selector but a fixed endpoint instead.

Comment: @begie so what's your setup now? are you able to reach your services externally ? do you mind sharing what you have  thx

Comment: I've just added my own answer. Please see below.